# REST and HATEOS definitions self-violating?

Tags: rest, hateoas, hal

QUESTION: Can HATEOAS in REST be considered a valid proposition when it is self-evidently internally contradictory : If an interface is said to *not* be RESTful (according to Fielding), when a Client cannot utilize the in-band data (URI's) from the Response Hypertext (Hypermedia) without reference to an external (out-of-band) document, and therefore tightly coupling Client and Server according to Fielding, how can we do anything but fail Roy Fielding's prima facie [assertion](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven)?

It seems to me that Fielding's exposition makes HATEOAS and REST an internally contradictory proposition that cannot be fulfilled with the current technology - unless someone knows how to it without referring to out-of-band data?

(EDIT) I suspect no-one is reading/has read Fielding's rant, so here's the *most* relevant piece:

"*A REST API should be entered with no prior knowledge beyond the initial URI (bookmark) and set of standardized media types that are appropriate for the intended audience (i.e., expected to be understood by any client that might use the API). From that point on, all application state transitions must be driven by client selection of server-provided choices that are present in the received representations or implied by the user’s manipulation of those representations. The transitions may be determined (or limited by) the client’s knowledge of media types and resource communication mechanisms, both of which may be improved on-the-fly (e.g., code-on-demand). **[Failure here implies that out-of-band information is driving interaction instead of hypertext.]***"

We all keep asserting that we *must* have out-of-band knowledge of the URI's available methods beyond the initial data stream. Note how Fielding very stridently tells us that this is failure. Yet, it's how we're all dong it, me included. But Fielding screams *No* back at us.

(EDIT: because no-one's reading ithe explanation).

Comment: ...so what are you asking us, exactly?

Comment: If you can't read the first two sentences that are a question, then I can't help you. The subsequent narrative explains why the question is relevant, so as to avoid off-the-cuff non-relevant 'answers', of which there are far too many on Stackoverflow.

Comment: "Driven by" does not mean "documented by". You cannot possibly deduce what an API call will do unless you read the documentation. REST is a method, a pattern and mechanism, but nobody has ever said that is can somehow magically convey meanings. What do you expect, a fully developed exhaustive [*mathesis universalis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathesis_universalis) encoded in an actual implementation of Leibniz's [*characteristica universalis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristica_universalis)?

Comment: You can always imagine the answer containing something like `<action><verb>GET</verb><link rel="deposit" href="/account/12345/deposit" /></action>` is that pleases you more. You still need to read the documentation to understand what GETting that URL will give you.

Comment: Fielding is explicit on this. A client must be able to navigate the Response URI's purely from the Hypermedia in the Response, or he says it is not RESTful. The absence of a 'method' typing for Hypermedia URI's makes this impossible to acheive for HTML. It's not about what I expect, it's about what Fielding says his Dissertation proposition requires. I'd be happy if Fielding came out and said "I was wrong. REST must necessarily become tightly coupled with knowledge of the Server API, and therefore my proposition that the Response Hypermedia is all you should need is false." - but he hasn't.

Comment: Check it for yourself here: http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driv‌​en, There is no provision for a 'method' or 'verb' element in the spec. Yet Fielding explicitly refutes the premise of the rather obtuse Leibnitz comment made above. I happen to agree with that comment, but Fielding does not, and it's Fielding's very strong rant about how we all do this, that forces me to ask the question.

Comment: Is your single concern about REST or HATEOAS that the response does not teach a client which method to use and which media-type to exchange? HTTP offers the [`OPTIONS`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.7) method a client can use in order to learn exactly that. That this method isn't widely used is not RESTs failure. Certain semantics are also already covered by the protocol itself, making them more explicit is therefore more or less redundant as they can be queried via `OPTIONS` as mentioned above or deduct from the protocol specification itself.

Comment: Note further, that the client and server exchange representations which both understand as agreed upon their content negotiation. If one of the representations isn't understood by the server an error will be returned teaching the client that what he sent doesn't make sense to the server. Media types are simple, plain text specifications of the syntax and semantics of a representation and both client and server couple to the respective media-types but not to each other.

Comment: @CelticPoet: I read those two sentences, but the way they're written means they come across as an angry rhetorical question, rather than trying to obtain information. The language in which your question is written means it come across as a rant - it gives the impression you've already made your mind up. Assuming that's not the case - i.e. you are genuinely seeking information - I'd strongly suggest rewriting the question along the lines of "I've read in AAA that XXX, but this seems to me to contradict YYY in BBB, what am I missing?" rather than "ZZZ is self-evidently internally contradictory".

Comment: So, @psmears, no, those are questions. Very specific questions. Fielding had a serious rant at us all for the way we're doing it - he says we're all misusing his definition of REST (and he invented it, so he's the authority). But when you consider that the HATEOAS definition is an integral part of REST's assertion, the two definitions become internally impossible to fulfill on the face of it. After a week of searching for any instance in which Fielding might have clarified it, I found nothing. So I asked the crew here in case there's some journal article or symposium exposition I didn't find.

Comment: @RomanVottner, so, you're suggesting that Fielding is (assuming?) we'll all make a second HTTP call per URI from the initial Response, and ask for Options, then read the ALLOW element, right? I considered that, but, not only does Fielding never even mention making two calls per URI, as Zac Stuart in Atlanta points out (http://zacstewart.com/2012/04/14/http-options-method.html), the feature is not implemented in almost any sites. We use Swagger to communicate it. So the question stands: If Fielding is means what he says, how do his REST and the HATEOAS definitions expect we'll do it?

Comment: @RomanVottner, we all do what you are describing - me too ... "the client and server exchange representations which both understand as agreed upon their content negotiation" - But Fielding says - vehemently - this is incorrect and that this very assumption by us as engineers is what makes him mad as a hatter at us. Fielding asserts very clearly that to be RESTful, you must only read the content of the initial Response. If you have to 'know' and hard-code from internal knowledge - "agreed upon", as you say - then you have too tightly coupled your Client and Server, and you are not RESTful.

Comment: No, you don't couple client and servers to each other but use the media types as intermediary. It will define the semantics and syntax exchanged and also if it simply uses URI or an extension of that. Just look at how HTML does it and how Web browsers use links to request further pages. Sure, plenty of pages exchanged are one of the HTML flavors, but again, the media type is the important part. Unfortunately HTML restricts itself to `POST` and `GET` methods in most cases, though the idea here still stands. I don't think a Web browser does implement some server specific thing

Comment: You cannot use a media-type to infer an HTML Verb from a URI. HTML media-types, like MIME "text/html", tell you nothing of what actions you can take on the URI, and hence you cannot use the URI response alone in order to 'navigate' those URI's, as Roy Fielding asserts REST requires. Simply saying "No you don't couple ..." also doesn't change the fact that Roy says doing exactly that _does_ in his definition tightly couple the Client to disqualified out-of-band data, and makes our apps SOA-RPC's, not RESTful API's. I know, it's infuriating, but Fielding is adamant about this.

Answer (score 0):

There are three pieces of prior knowledge that REST allows: the home page of the API (in browsers, this is supplied by the user typing into the address bar); an understanding of common media types, such as HTML (provided by browser developers); and link relations that inform a client application can look at when deciding what to do (e.g. `rel=stylesheet` links get automatically downloaded and parsed by graphical browsers to make the documents they render look pretty).

What REST prohibits is a client knowing it can do things like read an ID from a certain place on your webpage and then append it onto the end of `youtube.com/watch?v=` to get to a YouTube video. In stead, you should define a "video-clip" link relation and use your media type's hyperlinking mechanism to provide the full URL, not just the ID.

Comment: I use the phrases website and API interchangeably since a website is just a HTML API for human user agents.

Comment: Those things may be true, but they are not germain, and asserting that they are the _only_ restrictions directly contradicts the man who invented REST. Roy Fielding says that you may not use out-of-band 'documentation' to 'know' what HTTP Verb actions are possible on a URI. He says, very explicitly, that you must be able to derive all the information you need from the URI in the Response. Since you cannot know what Verb actions can be performed against a Response URI, we're mostly not RESTful. Just because we up-vote ourselves doesn't change the fact that Roy Fielding says we are all wrong.

Comment: I didn't say they were the only restrictions, and I didn't discuss HTTP methods. I did not intend to imply anything about them through omission of discussion, however since you bring it up: forms, OPTIONS, and trial-and-error are all RESTful ways for a client to learn about what methods are available. All resources are expected to support GET, HEAD, OPTIONS and TRACE.

Answer (score -1):

So, the answer to my question seems to be that *none* us know how to do it the way Fielding said it should be done, so none us know how to acheive a HATEOAS compliant RESTful API without violating Fielding's primary assertion regarding out-of-band data, and therefore making our app non-RESTful in so doing.

Everyone stridently believes they have this answer right, but we're all ignoring the fact that Roy Fielding says we are all wrong. He says we're all writing RPC's.

[Roy Fielding: REST APIs must be hypertext-driven](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven)
"I am getting frustrated by the number of people calling **any** HTTP-based interface a REST API"

It boils down to the fact that we are not building the kind of apps that lend themselves to Roy's thesis on REST. Indeed, he believes the proposition that we would render our URI's as part of CDATA that includes the "method" or that the context of the URI would self-evidently provide it, like the FORM element does. He explicitly rails against the OpenSocialst REST API stating that it is *not* RESTful.

Here: *“anchor elements with an href attribute create a hypertext link that, when selected, invokes a retrieval request (GET) on the URI corresponding to the CDATA-encoded href attribute.” Identifiers, methods, and media types are orthogonal concerns — methods are not given meaning by the media type. Instead, the media type tells the client either what method to use (e.g., anchor implies GET) or how to determine the method to use (e.g., form element says to look in method attribute). The client should already know what the methods mean (they are universal) and how to dereference a URI.*

I tend to design JSON responses that provide this approach:

```
GET /account/12345 HTTP/1.1
{
    "account": {
        "number": "12345",
        "currency": "usd",
        "balance": "100.00",
        "deposit": {
            "href": "/account/12345/deposit",
            "action": "POST"
        },
        "withdraw": {
            "href": "/account/12345/withdraw",
            "action": "POST"
        },
        "transfer": {
            "href": "/account/12345/transfer",
            "action": "POST"
        },
        "close": {
            "href": "/account/12345/close",
            "action": "DELETE"
        }
    }
}
```

... adding additional properties to the design as needed, but these are the basics.

I believe this allow the Client to be written to be RESTful, but in so doing I am using the Response Body, which Fielding says is not what he intended.

Answer (score -1):

No, REST and HATEOAS do not contradict each other. In fact the proposition doesn't even make sense because HATEOAS is part of the definition of REST. They aren't two separate things.

To better understand what Fielding means by out-of-band knowledge I suggest thinking about a web browser. A web browser is a generic client that implements a set of standards (HTTP, HTML, URI, etc). Any of the standards that the client implements can be thought of as in-band. Anything that is not expressed in one of the standards implemented by the generic client is out-of-band.

If you have a resource that looks like this

```
GET /some/resource HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "author": "/authors/me",
  "foo": 42
}
```

As a human, I can look at this and recognize that the value of "author" looks like a link and I can try to follow it, but a generic browser only recognizes it as plain JSON. It's just a string. Interpreting that "author" is a link requires out-of-band knowledge.

The solution is to choose a hypermedia media type that defines how to express a link. Here's that example expressed in HAL.

```
GET /some/resource HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/hal+json


{
  "_links": {
    "author": { "href": "/authors/me" }
  },
  "foo": 42
}
```

A generic client can be developed that understands HAL. My API and your API can both use the same client without knowing anything about each other or the client knowing about either API.

The question about how to know which method to use with a link is also up to the hypermedia media type to define. HTML does it by defining constructs whose semantics imply a method. The anchor tag `<a href="/foo">foo</a>` implies a GET request. The form tag has similar well defined semantics. A JSON based hypermedia format will have to define it's own structures and semantics for those structures. All of this is considered in-band because it's part of a standard that can be implemented by a generic browser.

So, if you want to get the Roy Fielding stamp of approval for your REST API, you need to be using a standardized generic hypermedia media type that is capable of describing everything your application needs to do. My favorite is JSON Hyper-Schema. It's the best at describing something like a form post without out-of-band knowledge because it uses a JSON Schema to describe what data the server expects.

Comment: Well, I hear what you say, but HAL is not Fielding's definition for HATEOAS or Resfulness, it is just one interpretation of how to get-to Fielding's definition, one among a number of competing approached. I note that PayPal uses a different standard, and I've worked on some that use Hydra and others that use JSON-LD. We use HAL where I work now, and we've interpreted 'type' as being the place to put the HTTP verb, but Kelly's spec doesn't actually say that. HAL may become the de-facto standard, but there is no "standard generic hypermedia", there are competing, conflicting candidates though.

Comment: Yes, there are many competing standards for generic hypermedia formats. I never meant to imply that HAL was the only/best/most-popular option. It was just an example. HAL is actually quite limited in it's hypermedia expressiveness. It's only Level 1 on the Hypermedia Maturity Model. https://8thlight.com/blog/jason-desrosiers/2018/05/30/the-hypermedia-maturity-model.html

Comment: Good answer. One small nit-pick: the only real difference between your two code examples is that the second one has a published schema. I don't agree that such a schema needs to be “generic” for the API to be RESTful, only that it be standardised within its field of use (i.e. available to all members—‘published’—and generally agreed upon within that group).

Comment: By "generic", I mean decoupled from any business data/logic. It just allows you to mark up your data with links and forms. It doesn't have to be public, but if it's generic, why not.